# What are the differences between 技術 and 技能?

Tags: nuances, words

What are the differences between 技術 and 技能?

Comment: 技能 means skill and 技術 means technology.

Comment: @Matt: It is more subtle than that.  For example, 運転技術 means “driving skills.”

Comment: So what is the correct answer to this question?
:)

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto: Nice, I didn't know that. That's why I only posted a comment. But I think it's fair to say that what I wrote above is *roughly* what it means. どう思いますか？

Comment: Thank you but I want to mean something like this: “京都以外の出身者の若い女性たちが、その芸術、芸能を伝承し、” or like this: “現在日本では、技術　技能の断絶への懸念が高まっている。”

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several diffrences, and I am not sure if I can list them all. The following is what I feel.

- 技能 is for established techonology/skill (typically traditional ones), whereas 技術 is any kind of techonology (typically modern ones).
- 技能 is attached to a human, whereas 技術 can be done by using machinery, human skills, improved planning of process, or combination of these.
- 技能 is inherited from a master to a younger generation, and has the implication that, once acheived, it stays permanently for the person. 技術 does not have that implication.